# Display short description on front end multi-store site

Tags: magento

Magento 1.9.1
Multi store load.  I would like the short description to show up on one store but not the other.

Here are the store views to product listing:
http://www.gas-sensing.com/portable-monitors.html
http://www.oxidationtech.com/products/ozone-monitors/handheld-ozone.html

On admin back-end under the product attribute "short description" I can check "Used in product listing".  However, this will be site wide.  I would like this to be store specific so that one site shows the short description on the front-end, and the other does not.

Is there an easy way to change this?

Comment: Product Attribute : Short Description is displayed only in PDP (Product Detail Page). Where on the Product Listing Page are you targetting?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display Short Description at Store specific level, is to make the attribute "Store View" specific.

**Steps**

> 1. Navigate to Catalog > Manage Products
> 2. Choose your Product > on the extreme LEFT - Default Configuration > Select a Store View (where you DO NOT want to display the value)
> 3. In the General Tab, find the Short Description - Make the value empty - Deselect the checkbox (Use Default Value)

Screenshots:

**Hoping you have the similar website structure**

[image]

[image]

[image]

> 4. Save Product

Run reindexing using System > Index Management

Let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding...